# How to update on cascade in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's look at this example database:
[image: Example database]

As we can see, person depends on the city (person.city_id is a foreign key). I don't delete rows, I just set them inactive (active=0). After setting city inactive, how can I automatically set all persons who are dependent on this city inactive? Is there a better way than writing triggers?

EDIT: I am interested only in setting person's rows inactive, not setting them active.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses cascading foreign keys to do what you describe:

```
mysql> create table city (
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  name varchar(45), 
  active tinyint, 
  primary key (id),
  unique key (id, active));

mysql> create table person (
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  city_id int,
  active tinyint, 
  primary key (id), 
  foreign key (city_id, active) references city (id, active) on update cascade);

mysql> insert into city (name, active) values ('New York', 1);

mysql> insert into person (city_id, active) values (1, 1);

mysql> select * from person;
+----+---------+--------+
| id | city_id | active |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+

mysql> update city set active = 0 where id = 1;

mysql> select * from person;
+----+---------+--------+
| id | city_id | active |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      0 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Tested on MySQL 5.5.31.

Comment: Would this restrict a person from being inactive when a city is active?  I like the answer though.

Comment: Yes, the person.active field would be constrained to be exactly the same as the corresponding city.active.  If you need to allow them to be different (which is easy to imagine, but you didn't state this requirement in your question), you need to use a trigger or do the change in both tables from application code.

Comment: Great answer, but after I set city active, all persons will also be set active and I don't want this to happen. Only setting persons inactive.

Comment: Yep, fair enough.  My solution works but doesn't meet all your requirements.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should reconsider how you define a person to be active.. Instead of having active defined twice, you should just keep it in the city table and have your SELECT statements return Person WHERE city.active = 1..

But if you must.. you could do something like:

```
UPDATE city C
LEFT JOIN person P ON C.id = P.city
SET C.active = 0 AND P.active = 0
WHERE C.id = @id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, just WHERE is not enough. This db is just an example, the real one is more complicated. I'll try with LEFT JOIN if there will be no better solutions. Thanks!