# How to reference multiple columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Teams and Players. At any given time entire teams which many players can belong to are either active or inactive. I would like to be able to update the isActive column in the Teams table and have the change reflected across all players in the player table that have that same Team_id. I can't seem to find the way to do this. So far I have:

```
create Teams (
team_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
team_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
isActive int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

create Players (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
player_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
team_id int NOT NULL,
isActive int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES Teams(team_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
???
);
```

??? I want to do something like: `FOREIGN KEY (isActive) REFERENCES Teams(isActive) ON UPDATE CASCADE`, but obviously this is not working.

How can I create my tables so I can 'ON UPDATE CASCADE' on a non-primary key column (Players.isActive) while also retaining my regular PRIMARY KEY -- ON UPDATE CASCADE, to make all players with that team_id "see" the change automatically to the isActive update in the Teams table?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: to achieve this you can use triggers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Why do you need to store this twice?

Comment: Thanks for the responses all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create a foreign key from `players` to `teams` that includes `isActive` column, then you could follow what is described in the following thread,

[How to update on cascade in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779552/how-to-update-on-cascade-in-mysql)

Otherwise it can be achieved by using triggers

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

If using triggers is an acceptable solution then you could do something like the following in order to modify all players' `isActive` value belonging to a team that has changed the value of `isActive`,

```
CREATE TRIGGER `upate_inactive_players` AFTER UPDATE ON `Teams`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (OLD.isActive <> NEW.isActive) THEN
        UPDATE `Players` set isActive = NEW.isActive where team_id = OLD.team_id
    END IF;
END
```

Please note that this will have the consequence of activating players, that have been deactivated independently, when activating their team.

Comment: Thanks for the response melc :)