# Update foreign key in all tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 35 tables with a `country_id`

I would like to do the following (pseudocode)

```
UPDATE {all tables containing country_id} 
SET country_id = 1 
WHERE country_id = 2
```

Can somebody help construct this sql?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks in advance for what, precisely?

Comment: @HoboSapiens I would like help constructing the SQL, why the downvote?

Comment: You'd have to ask the downvoter, but I'd guess it's because they think this is a poor question. I tend to agree.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Why is it poor? It will save me running 35 different queries if it can be done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update on cascade in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779552/how-to-update-on-cascade-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe my code help you to found solution.

I had similar problem to your. My database has 76 foreign keys to `users`.`id`, and I need to increase all ID for 10. The most simple way to do it is set foreign keys ON UPDATE state to CASCADE. But I make mistake when I was creating all FK, so all of this were set to NO ACTION.

Fortunately I found solution. This code generate SQL query to UPDATE all FK refferenced to `user`.`id` in my database:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT("
        ALTER TABLE `",TABLE_NAME,"`
        DROP FOREIGN KEY `",CONSTRAINT_NAME,"`;
        ALTER TABLE `",TABLE_NAME,"`
        ADD CONSTRAINT `",CONSTRAINT_NAME,"` FOREIGN KEY (`",COLUMN_NAME,"`)
        REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE CASCADE;
    ")
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'users' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'id';
```

Comment: If you want to change all table and column, and only one schema you should change:
REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
to:
REFERENCES `",REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME ,"` (`",REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME ,"`)

and:
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name';